# wait of condition_variable in C++ will consume CPU resource?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, cpu-usage, condition-variable

I ran the following snip of code in both Linux and Windows to check whether cv.wait() will occupy the CPU during the wait period.

```cpp
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable, std::cv_status

std::condition_variable cv;

int main()
{
    std::mutex mtx;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    cv.wait_for(lck, std::chrono::milliseconds(100000), []() {return false; });
    return 0;
}
```

The result shows a big difference.

- In Linux, I check it with `htop`, the usage of this process is 100%.
- In Windows, I check it with `task manager`, the usage is prone to 0.

> By the way, if I start a new thread and put the above code in that, the usage in Linux is almost 0.

It puzzles me a lot, my question are:

1. whether the cv.wait will give up CPU resource which is similar with sleep？
2. why it differs a lot in multi-thread in Linux?

Comment: Can't reproduce on Linux, I get ~0% CPU usage.

Comment: no sane implementation will make a wait consume CPU. I also get 0% CPU on Linux.

Comment: Looks like it depends whether the program is compiler with `-pthread` or not on Linux. Which makes sense: If the program isn't multithreaded at all, waiting for a condition variable would be a guaranteed self-deadlock, so causing `cv.wait*()` to return immediately in a single threaded program is both permitted (because spurious wakeups are) and arguably the lesser evil when confronted with badly written programs. If the predicated version of `wait_for()` is built on top of a simple `wait_for()`, then busy-waiting is a natural consequence of bad programming.

Comment: Repproduce step: copy the above code into `main.cpp`, then run `g++ main.cpp` and `./a.out`, type `htop` in another shell.